# Why is the component rerendering after setting state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-lifecycle

```
export function App(props) {
  const [number,setNumber] = useState(0);
  console.log(number,'one')
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(number,'two')
    setNumber(1);
  },[number]);
  console.log(number,'three')
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {number}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App(props) {
  const [number,setNumber] = useState(0);
  console.log(number,'one')
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(number,'two')
    setNumber(1);
  },[number]);
  console.log(number,'three')
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {number}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Given the code as above, I expected the output of console.log to be as follows

```
Expected output
0 one
0 three
0 two
1 one
1 three
1 two
```

Because during the initial rendering, the value of 'number' changed to 1. In the subsequent renderings, even if setNumber(1) is called, I expected 'number' not to change, so I thought there would be no re-rendering.

However, the actual output was as follows

```
Actual output
0 one
0 three
0 two
1 one
1 three
1 two
1 one
1 three
```

I was under the impression that if the state values are the same, no re-render would occur. However, even though the state values did not change, why is there an additional re-render happening?

Comment: Because in your `useEffect` dependency array you have `number`, when you `setNumber(1)` it will update the state which causes re-rendering, so it will log again.

Comment: But then @Saidamir how can you explain the last rerender 1 one
1 three

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence can be explained by the following order of events.

1. Your `App` component renders with the initial value `0` for `number`. This causes the output `0 one` and `0 tree`.
2. After the render is complete the `useEffect` callback is fired. This causes the output `0 two`.
3. Because `useEffect` called `setNumber` (from `0` to `1`) React will register a state updated and re-render the component. Causing the output `1 one` and `1 tree`.
4. Because the `useEffect` `number` dependency changed from `0` to `1` the `useEffect` callback is invoked again. Causing the output `0 two`.
5. Because `useEffect` called  `setNumber` (from `1` to `1`) React will register a state update (even though you use the same value) and re-render the component. Causing the output `1 one` and `1 tree`.
6. The `useEffect` callback is **not** called this time because the dependency `number` did not change. So this is where the render stops.

If you want to avoid the last render, you should not call `setNumber` if the value is already what it should be.

```
// avoid `setNumber(1)` if `number` is already `1` to prevent the final render
if (number != 1) setNumber(1);
```

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App(props) {
  const [number,setNumber] = useState(0);
  console.log(number,'one')
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(number,'two')
    if (number != 1) setNumber(1);
  },[number]);
  console.log(number,'three')
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      {number}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(<App />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```